# What does wikipedia use for text and revision diffs

Tags: php, string, text, diff, compare

I'm trying to take 2 versions of text (10 pages long) and compare the 2 to produce the difference. I know Wikipedia has a similar feature to compare revisions. Does anyone know what they use? I'm hoping they're using a php-driven solution.

Comment: You could just RTFS: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [implimentation of diff in php](http://www.holomind.de/phpnet/diff.src.php). I haven't used it but it's a start. There is also something called [PHP inline diff](http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/) that you can check out